# Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) in c++

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

This code when executed displays the expected output but prints `segmentation fault (core dumped)` at the end :

```
string str[4] = {
    "Home",
    "Office",
    "Table",
    "Bar"
};

for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout << str[i] << "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
Home
Office
Table
Bar
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the signinficance of segmentation fault (core dumped). I searched and it seems an error like that occurs when you try to access unallocated memory, so, what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Use `g++ -Wall -g` to compile and debug with `gdb`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should write:

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) //0,1,2,3 = total 4 values
{
    cout << str[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Or better, `#define NEL(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array) ... for (int i  = 0; i < NEL(str); i++)` ...

Comment: I don't believe in macros... sorry.

Comment: I don't believe in dangerous duplication of information, and my belief is a backbone principle of software engineering.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: The above macro by Jim is trivial to implement as a function. This code is bad as it tightly couples the code to a particular data set. You want to be able to modify the data without having to scan your code for tight coupling and code that needs to be modified.

Comment: You really should learn to enable warnings and debugging info for the compiler (e.g. use `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger `gdb`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ Arrays are 0-based so you cannot access str[4], since its indexes range 0-3.
You allocated an array, length of 4:

```
string str[4]
```

Then your loop must terminate when:

```
i < 4
```

Rather than `i < 5`.

Answer (score 3):

counter should be from zero to three. For loop needs modification.

Answer (score 3):

`str` is a `string[4]`, so it has 4 elements, which means indices 0-3 are valid. You are also accessing index 4.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting segmentation fault because you trying to access an element which does not exists i.e. `str[4]`
The possible indices are from 0-3.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing data past the end of your array. `str` is an array of size 4, but you are accessing a fifth element in your loop, that is why you get a seg fault